DataGrid flickers and lags when resizing columns - How to resolve?
I am using the Material UI DataGrid in my NextJS project, and I'm experiencing issues when resizing columns. The resizing is not smooth, and the grid flickers. I expected the resizing to be seamless. How can I fix this?
Here is my code:
"use client";

import {
  DrawerMenu,
  neutral100,
} from "ownComponents";
import {
  AddCard,
  AppRegistration,
  Description,
  Home,
  Inbox,
  Payment,
  Subject,
} from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGridPremium, GridColDef } from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";
import { useState } from "react";

const columns: GridColDef<(typeof rows)[number]>[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", flex: 1 },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    flex: 1,
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last name",
    flex: 1,
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    flex: 1,
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    valueGetter: (value, row) => `${row.firstName || ""} ${row.lastName || ""}`,
    flex: 1,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 14 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 31 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 31 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 11 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 },
];

export default function Page() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <Grid container flex={1} bgcolor={neutral100}>
      <DrawerMenu
        width={360}
        open={isOpen}
        toggleDrawer={setIsOpen}
        logoImage="/logo.png"
        favIcon="/favicon.png"
        accountName={"Kevin van Bommel"}
        accountEmail={"kevin.van.bommel@2-controlware.com"}
        listItems={[
          { name: "Home", icon: <Home />, link: "/" },
          { name: "Contracs", icon: <Description />, link: "/contracts" },
          { name: "Applications", icon: <Inbox />, link: "/applications" },
          { name: "Price groups", icon: <AddCard />, link: "/pricegroups" },
          {
            name: "Contract entries",
            icon: <Subject />,
            link: "/contractentries",
          },
          { name: "Customers", icon: <Payment />, link: "/customers" },
          {
            name: "Registrations",
            icon: <AppRegistration />,
            link: "/registrations",
          },
        ]}
      />
      <Grid
        item
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        flex={1}
        overflow="auto"
        p={2}
      >
        <DataGridPremium
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

What I'm trying to do is give my grid flex 1 so that it is responsive and if i expand my DrawerMenu is that my whole page is responsive, but my DataGrid is not running smooth can anyone help me with this?
